# how to check which radio button was chosen in ios swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, radio-button

In my developing app, it has four radio buttons and one normal button. User should choose anyone of the radio button and proceed with normal button. I want to know which radio button was chosen by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Great question this was my question too! 
You can use this method in Button Action

```
if button1.isSelected == true {
print("button1 Selected")
} else  if button2.isSelected == true {
print("button2 Selected")
} else if button3.isSelected == true {   
   print("button3 Selected")
} else if button4.isSelected == true {
print("button4 Selected")
}
```

of course there is another way that I don't know But I think This will help you